# Facebook Photo uploading into "foreign" album instead of "*appName* Photos"?

Tags: facebook, upload, facebook-graph-api, photo

I am successfully uploading photos with my iPhone App and the corresponding Graph API calls, and it ends up properly in an (automatically created) album "*appName* Photos" on a new account w/o existing albums. Uploading to my own account, however, puts the photo to "Camera + Photos", the first of multiple albums existing for my account, instead of creating a new one for my app.
Anything I need to consider specifically to enforce creation of an app-related album? Do I need to go through an explicit album creation process first? I thought all the required information would be provided by the logon procedure, containing the appID (and seemingly does when using the "empty" account)?

**EDIT:**
I just had the albums programmatically listed, and actually an according album WAS created and is returned in the list of albums now, however it does not show up and contains no photos. So maybe it is rather a bug that the actual upload is taking place to the next album in the row (maybe some race condition on the FB side)?

Thx for insight, habitoti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it should work that way (as described in the docs) but it appears to be a recent change to no longer enforce creation of an app-related album but to use a default album for all posted photos that aren't explicitly added to a specific album.

You'll want to use the procedure described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) (look at the second chunk of code) to ensure that it creates an application-named album.

Comment: Thanks...it's really annoying that FB changes the behavior around their APIs all the time :-(

Comment: Well, that's the price you pay to play: the API remains the same but the behavior changes at will.

Comment: Call me old-school -- to me an API and the documented semantics behind it somehow belong together ;-)

Comment: Just added some additional findings to the initial post -- maybe it is rather a bug?

Comment: You're not wrong, you're not wrong. Welcome to the new age :)